# Hessian matrix and strictly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-definite, hessian-matrix

I understand that the positive definiteness of the Hessian matrix is a sufficient condition for a function to be strictly convex, i.e. $$f''(x)\succ0, \forall x\in\Omega\implies f(x)\text{ is strictly convex in }\Omega.$$

A counterexample of the inverse statement is $f(x) = x^4$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The second derivative is $12x^2$, and it equals $0$ when $x=0$. So the second derivative is not positive definite in $\mathbb{R}$.

I wonder under what regularity condition (e.g. on $\Omega$ and/or $f(x)$) does strictly convexity of $f(x)$ implies positive definite Hessian matrix? Or is there any probability statement, like Hessian matrix is positive definite with probability 1?

Comment: Do you assume that $f''$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, let's assume $f''$ is continous.